# Track/Verify/Update a MySQL result by user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of a schedule where volunteers can check their shifts. I'm going to email them a link to the page where they enter their email addresses into an HTML form to access this information.

Is there a way I can track which emails are queried so I can resend the schedule link to those who haven't accessed the database?

If necessary, I could add an additional 'confirmed' check box to the results and have that update the database. I like that idea, but I'm not sure how to implement (or the terminology for what that action would be).

Edit: Here's the code I'm using to implement. However I'm not getting results in the confirmed column.

```
                $db = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db");

    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE volConfirm SET confirmed = TRUE WHERE email = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * from volConfirm WHERE email = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    // construct your output here using $row to access database record
    echo "<h2>" . $row['agreeName'] . "</h2>";
    echo "<p> You have been assigned as a volunteer for:" . $row['position'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Your shift times are scheduled for:" . $row['shift_times'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Your shift has been confirmed:" . $row['confirmed'] . "</p>";
    }
```

Comment: you can add a field in your table (visited) when user enters email update it from 0 to 1.

Comment: Are you getting any MySQL errors? Change the fourth line into `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`. Also, in your code above, you should use mysql_real_escape_string to escape the user input. Never trust user input :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Hi Daan- I'm not getting any errors when I add the 'or die'. (Updated code in OP)

Comment: Now I'm getting the error 'Query is empty'- (updated code above)

Comment: @Commandrea: See my updated answer.  I'm using prepared statements via [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to avoid SQL injection.  The first half updates the new `confirmed` flag in the table, whilst the second half fetches the table values for you to then output as you see fit.

Comment: Hi eggy- I really appreciate your help-- after working with the updated script, I'm now getting an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() -- looking into that now.

Comment: BUT WAIT! Good news...even though I'm getting that error, it confirmed the volunteer :) Victory neareth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something along the lines of:

1. Add a new column to your volunteers table

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Volunteers ADD COLUMN Confirmed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;
   ```
2. Have the PHP in the submission page update that column:

   ```
   UPDATE Volunteers SET Confirmed = TRUE WHERE Email = 'foo@bar.com';
   ```

   In your code snippet:

   ```
   $db = new mysqli("dbhostname", "username", "password", "dbschema");

   $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE volConfirm SET confirmed = TRUE WHERE email = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
   $stmt->execute();

   $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * from volConfirm WHERE email = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
   $result = $stmt->get_result();

   while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
     // construct your output here using $row to access database record
   }
   ```
3. At some point in the future, get a list of all users who have not yet accessed the page:

   ```
   SELECT Email FROM Volunteers WHERE Confirmed = FALSE;
   ```

Comment: Hey Eggy-Thanks! I've got the column added (#1) however, what should I replace 'users' with? I tried my 'volConfirm' table key but it's not updating the DB.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  `Users` in #2 should have been `Volunteers` (i.e. the table name).  Corrected.

Comment: Okay- I did that and it didn't work anyways :) I think I'm running into an issue w/ the 'foo@bar.com' -- as the email ='$email' (or the query input by the user)

Comment: Also, do you know what it's called when we use a 'mystery' value such as the input $email address and carry that over to another portion of the code?

Comment: You don't want to be writing `WHERE EMAIL = '$email'`, **especially** if the value of `$email` is outside your control: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)'s school did that and they got burnt.  As far as why it isn't working in this test case, you'll probably need to provide a little more information (did you get an error? what data is in your volunteers table? can you `SELECT` the volunteer okay?)

Comment: The 'mystery' value is known as an unsafe or 'unsanitised' variable; it poses the risk of 'SQL injection'.  Is that what you were after?

Comment: When I echo the results on the output page, everything selects up to the 'confirmed' where it is echoing '0'. (I'm using stripslashes, just left that out to declutter.)

Comment: Ah, just seen your revised code in the question.  You appear to be missing a call to `mysql_query($mysql_query);` in order to run the second/update command.  You'll also want to run that before `mysql_query($query);` in order that the selected results include the modified `Confirmed` column (if that's what you're after).

Comment: I couldn't use get_result due to my PHP settings, I believe, but I got it going with bind_result in its place. Thank you for your time!